# How to stop the video in Divi background at the last frame

Tags: video, frame

I want your help about **Divi theme**. I set a video background in a fullwidth section. I disabled loop so the video plays only once when the page is loaded. My problem is this: I want the video to **stop at the last frame**. Now, when the video is completed the image which displays is the first frame. 
Any suggestions??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and you can refer to "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I figured out that Divi uses MediaPlayer.js which has an option "autoRewind" which you can set to false.

I modified the ElegantThemes recommended loop disable javascript snippet to include it. This worked for me:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.no-loop').each(function() {
            $(this).find('video').removeAttr('loop');
        });
        $('video').mediaelementplayer({
            autoRewind: false
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you simply input a new array for mediaelementplayer, you will override settings configured by DIVI. To avoid this, modify the array already provided by DIVI: `window._wpmejsSettings.autoRewind = false;`, then you just pass the original array to the player: `$(this).find('video').removeAttr('loop').mediaelementplayer(window._wpmejsSettings);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $(this).find('video').removeAttr('loop');

        $('video').mediaelementplayer({
            autoRewind: false
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the Java Script in the header: `Divi / Theme Option / Integration / Add code` in the header, remembering to activate the option "enable code in the head".